# Quiz Images answers

Tags: android, imagebutton

I am trying to create a quiz for children on the autistic spectrum. I want to use images for answers or better yet, buttons with images somthing like this https://gyazo.com/2309e055184a4840c23a07bda0a5bf63. My app works, but when I do the quiz, I can't get the correct answers, only wrong. Seems like the if statement doesn't work. I want four static answers and only have the `ImageView`s change. I don't know what to do.

```
public class Category2 extends AppCompatActivity{

    private database2 database2 = new database2();
    private ImageButton imageChoice1,imageChoice2,imageChoice3,imageChoice4;
    ImageView iv_Pic;
    private Button imageAnswerSpace;
    int quizCount = 0;
    int rightAnswerCount = 0;
    private int mAnswer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category2);

        iv_Pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_Pic);
        imageChoice1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
        imageChoice2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageview2);
        imageChoice3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageview3);
        imageChoice4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageview4);

        newQ();  

        imageChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {    
                if (v.getId() == R.id.imageview1 && (v.getId() == mAnswer)) {
                    Toast.makeText(Category2.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    newQ();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Category2.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    newQ();
                }
            }
        });

        imageChoice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.imageview2 &&  (v.getId()== mAnswer)){
                    Toast.makeText(Category2.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    newQ();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Category2.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    newQ();
                }
            }
        });

        imageChoice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.imageview3 && (v.getId()== mAnswer)) {
                    Toast.makeText(Category2.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                    newQ();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Category2.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    newQ();
                }
            }
        });

        imageChoice4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.imageview4 && (v.getId()== mAnswer)) {
                    Toast.makeText(Category2.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    newQ();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Category2.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    newQ();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void newQ() {

        iv_Pic.setImageResource(database2.getImages(quizCount));

        ImageView changeImage0 = findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
        changeImage0.setImageResource(database2.getChoice1(quizCount));

        ImageView changeImage1 = findViewById(R.id.imageview2);                    
        changeImage1.setImageResource(database2.getChoice2(quizCount));

        ImageView changeImage3 = findViewById(R.id.imageview3);        
        changeImage3.setImageResource(database2.getChoice3(quizCount));

        ImageView changeImage4 = findViewById(R.id.imageview4);
        changeImage4.setImageResource(database2.getChoice4(quizCount));

        mAnswer = database2.getCorrectAnswer(quizCount);

        if (quizCount < 4) {
            quizCount++;
        } else if (quizCount == 4) {
            quizCount = 0;
        }
    }
}

public class database2 {

    private Integer mImages[] = {
        R.drawable.sad,
        R.drawable.happy,
        R.drawable.fear,
        R.drawable.angry,
    };
    public static int mChoices[] [] = {
        {
           R.drawable.ic_angry,
           R.drawable.ic_sad,
           R.drawable.ic_scared,
           R.drawable.ic_smiling
        }, {
           R.drawable.ic_angry,
           R.drawable.ic_sad,
           R.drawable.ic_scared,
           R.drawable.ic_smiling
       }, {
           R.drawable.ic_angry,
           R.drawable.ic_sad,
           R.drawable.ic_scared,
           R.drawable.ic_smiling
        }, {
           R.drawable.ic_angry,
           R.drawable.ic_sad,
           R.drawable.ic_scared,
           R.drawable.ic_smiling
        }
    };

    private Integer mCorrectAnswer[] = {
        R.drawable.ic_sad,
        R.drawable.ic_smiling,
        R.drawable.ic_scared,
        R.drawable.ic_angry
    };

    public Integer getImages(int a){
        Integer image = mImages[a];
        return image;
    }
    public Integer getChoice1(int a){
        int choice0 = mChoices[a][0];
        return choice0;
    }
    public Integer getChoice2(int a){
        int choice1 = mChoices[a][1];
        return choice1;
    }
    public Integer getChoice3(int a){
        int choice2 = mChoices[a][2];
        return choice2;
    }
    public Integer getChoice4(int a){
        int choice3 = mChoices[a][3];
        return choice3;
    }

    public Integer getCorrectAnswer(int a){
        Integer answer = mCorrectAnswer[a];
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried printing out the v.getId() is? this is a hint. run a system.out.println on v.getid() and I think youll find your solution

Comment: code properly re-indented by an autistic programmer. while I think it is overly complicated, when using `resId` - instead of some kind of matrix, which would tell apart right and wrong. I'd hint for `View.setTag()` and `View.getTag()`.

Comment: v.getId() == (R.id.imageview1) is redundant because v is the view being clicked and each view has it's own setOnClickListener().

Comment: v.getId() == R.id.imageview2 and all of these are redundant
remove those also

Comment: can you give me an example with Tags just for the first button?? Thx for your time @MartinZeitler

Comment: @LeeroyΜ. think that `database2` could be written much simpler, than having it all represented as `R.drawable`. the most simple use of `.setTag()` would be, to simply tag the view which is the correct answer. try to use the `R.drawable` names only once in your code, in order to improve readability (the more readable, the more obvious it becomes).

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're always seeing a 'wrong' answer is you're comparing a view Id to a drawable Id in the onClick listener. `v.getId()== mAnswer`. mAnswer is one of

```
private Integer mCorrectAnswer[] ={
        R.drawable.ic_sad,
        R.drawable.ic_smiling,
        R.drawable.ic_scared,
        R.drawable.ic_angry
};
```

whereas v.getId() is one of

```
R.id.imageview1
R.id.imageview2
R.id.imageview3
R.id.imageview4
```

As a short-term solution you could change mCorrectAnswer to use ImageView ids instead of drawable ids. However that will likely be difficult to maintain, so it would be better to use different logic that doesn't depend on resource Ids.

Answer (score 0):

the answers array should look alike this:

```
private Integer mCorrectAnswer[] ={
    R.id.ic_sad,
    R.id.ic_smiling,
    R.id.ic_scared,
    R.id.ic_angry
};
```

and it has to be compared with `mCorrectAnswer.get(quizCount)`.